# Invalid symbol - Binance Api

Tags: python, bots, binance

I'm trying to scrape the Open Interest of all tickers by binance api. However, the function `client.futures_open_interest(symbol=every_symbol)`reported an "APIError(code=-1121): Invalid symbol" error.

```
from binance import Client, ThreadedWebsocketManager, ThreadedDepthCacheManager

client = Client(apikey, secret)

exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()


for i in range(1985):#Total number of tickers
    every_symbol = exchange_info['symbols'][i]["symbol"]
    oi = client.futures_open_interest(symbol=every_symbol)
    print(oi)
```

As Far As I Can Tell `symbol` requires str, like`(symbol="BTCUSDT")`, so I use `str()` into `exchange_info['symbols'][i]["symbol"]`,like this

```
str(exchange_info['symbols'][i]["symbol"])
```

But it didn't work as well
how to solve this problem?
thanks

Comment: What is the value of `every_symbol`? Have you tried printing it out?

Comment: It's just a variable that I set.

Comment: `every_symbol = str(exchange_info['symbols'][0]["symbol"])`
`print(every_symbol)` #output->ETHBTC
@gmdev

Comment: Does the Binance API accept multiple symbols? ETH is the symbol for Ethereum and BTC is Bitcoin. Those are two different symbols. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Thank you @gmdev, I found the problem. since Binance Api dose not provide this trading pair. just some specific symbol. Therefore, it output Invalid symbol.